# Changing separator of datetime/datetime2 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I have problem using dates in laravel + SQL Server, because I have this error:

> InvalidArgumentException
>
> Trailing data

I need stored `13-02-2020 09:02:19.6340000` versus `13.02.2020 09:02:19.6340000`
Dates separator is `.`. Here Laravel carbon needs '-'.

How can I change this?

```
Laravel 6.2
SQL server 2016
```

Comment: you can use the replace function to replace dot with - while selecting the record.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow here. SQL Server doesn't store dates in a format, they are binary values. If you're using the correct datatypes, then formatting isn't an issue, as there is not formatting. This makes it sound like your storing dates as a `varchar`, and if so that is your *real* problem.

Comment: i tryed datetime and datetime2

Comment: The **`varchar`** value `'13.02.2020 09:02:19.6340000'` may fail to be inserting into a `datetime`/`datetime2` yes, because when SQL Server received a **`varchar`** representing a Date and Time it'll expect hyphens (`-`) as the date part separator. But if your data is stored as a `datetime`/`datetime2` then, like I said, they have no formats, so any application would be able to natively read the date and time data type (nor as a `varchar`). The only reason it wouldn't be able to is because you're using the wrong data type, either in storage or implicit/explicit conversion.

Comment: can be it changed with SET commands? it allows set datetimeformat but not a separator. and as i know ms sql sends datetime answer in binary format.

Comment: also i use freetds with 'auto' protocol detection. before i tryed all versions and not mention any changes except 4.2 not working at all. maybe some php *.ini setttings?